# Ruby-mysql troubles - Getting error while trying to use mysql module for Ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using Ruby v2.0 AND i'm using the Ruby-mysql v2.9.14 connector from here: https://rubygems.org/gems/ruby-mysql

I'm getting a number of errors while running this code:

```
require 'mysql'

begin
  connection = Mysql.new 'localhost', 'root', 'root'
  connection.list_dbs.each do |db|
    puts db
  end

rescue Mysql::Error => e
  puts e.errno
  puts e.error

ensure
  connection.close if connection
end
```

ERROR:

```
No such file or directory - "/tmp/mysql.sock" (Errno::ENOENT)
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/ruby-mysql-2.9.14/lib/mysql/protocol.rb:150:in `new'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/ruby-mysql-2.9.14/lib/mysql/protocol.rb:150:in `block in initialize'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/timeout.rb:52:in `timeout'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/ruby-mysql-2.9.14/lib/mysql/protocol.rb:147:in `initialize'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/ruby-mysql-2.9.14/lib/mysql.rb:115:in `new'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/ruby-mysql-2.9.14/lib/mysql.rb:115:in `connect'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/ruby-mysql-2.9.14/lib/mysql.rb:50:in `new'
from /Users/Joakim/Google Drive/Skole/IT/Ruby/Modul 6/ruby-mysql.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
from -e:1:in `load'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

My teacher tells me that it's the 'driver' crashing, but I'm not sure - is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: Are you sure to have a R/W /tmp folder on your host ?

Answer (score 0):

The driver tried to connect via socket file `/tmp/mysql.sock`, which is not available in your system (You can check for the file). The driver assumed you wanted to connect via socket file because you specified `localhost`.

The is what the driver [does](https://github.com/tmtm/ruby-mysql/blob/master/lib/mysql.rb#L118):

```
@host_info = (host.nil? || host == "localhost") ? 'Localhost via UNIX socket' : "#{host} via TCP/IP"
```

Try changing `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`.

**EDITED**

It seems that you use a custom port for mysql, 8889. So you need to specify that when connecting to the database:

```
connection = Mysql.new 'localhost', 'root', 'root', nil, 8889
```

Here is the snippet for the [method definition](https://github.com/tmtm/ruby-mysql/blob/master/lib/mysql.rb#L110):

```
  # Connect to mysqld.
  # @param [String / nil] host hostname mysqld running
  # @param [String / nil] user username to connect to mysqld
  # @param [String / nil] passwd password to connect to mysqld
  # @param [String / nil] db initial database name
  # @param [Integer / nil] port port number (used if host is not 'localhost' or nil)
  # @param [String / nil] socket socket file name (used if host is 'localhost' or nil)
  # @param [Integer / nil] flag connection flag. Mysql::CLIENT_* ORed
  # @return self
  def connect(host=nil, user=nil, passwd=nil, db=nil, port=nil, socket=nil, flag=0)
```

Comment: Alright, Now I'm getting the following error:
 `/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/ruby-mysql-
    2.9.14/lib/mysql/protocol.rb:153:in 'initialize': Connection refused - 
    connect(2) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)`

Comment: @JoakimK.S.S. Can you connect using mysql client to `127.0.0.1:3306`?

Comment: `in 'initialize': getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known (SocketError)`

I tried earlier with `127.0.0.1:8889` and got the same error. I'm trying to connect to a mysql server run by MAMP on my macbook.

Comment: @JoakimK.S.S.Try setting port argument, like, `connection = Mysql.new 'localhost', 'root', 'root', nil, 8889`

Comment: Great. I have updated the answer. You should update your question to mention the custom port you use.